# Email POST data with Content-type: application/xml

Tags: php, xml, post, phpmailer

I want to see XML data that is being POSTed via email.

The process:

1) XML POST is made to a PHP script.

2) The PHP script simply mails me the $_POST data via `print_r($_POST, true)` as the message.

I am using PHPMailer and SimpleXML to accomplish this.

Here is my code which POSTs the XML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<lead/>');
$post_body = array_flip($template['post_body']);
array_walk_recursive($post_body, array($xml, 'addChild'));

$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/xml\r\n",
       'content' => $xml->asXML(),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($template['address'], null, $context);
```

`$post_body` is an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [testbuyer] => buyerName
    [tdunn5e@hatena.ne.jp] => testEmail
    [Timothy] => leadFirstName
    [world] => customTest2
)
```

Here is my code which sends the email:

```
try
{
    $mailer = new PHPMailer();
    $mailer->isSMTP();
    $mailer->Host = EMAIL_HOST;
    $mailer->Port = EMAIL_PORT;
    $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mailer->Username = EMAIL_USERNAME;
    $mailer->Password = EMAIL_PASSWORD;
    $mailer->setFrom(EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    $mailer->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com');
    $mailer->Subject = 'Test POST';
    $mailer->Body = print_r($_POST, true);      
    $mailer->send();

    $response = 'Mail sent OK';
} 
catch (phpmailerException $e)
{ 
   $response = $e->errorMessage();
} 
catch (Exception $e)
{ 
   $response = $e->getMessage();
}
```

I receive the email fine, but the message just shows an empty array. It looks like this:

```
Array
(
)
```

Why is this happening? I just want to see the XML in the message so I can verify its all working properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you retrieving the $_POST data?

Comment: In an email. See my OP for details.

Comment: Your mail code looks fine, suggesting that `$_POST` doesn't contain what you think it does. Debug one thing at a time - Check what's in it before trying to email it. Also you've wrapped yor PHPMailer code in a `try` block, but not told PHPMailer to enable exceptions - pass `true` to the constructor to do that.